# Why cant i change my array value? But if i add address pointer to array, it works

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, php-7.4

I have a code block to return as a json as follow;

```
    $data = $this->regionRepository->getDistrictsByGivenTravelTag();//returns an array

    foreach ($data as $city){
        $city["is_fav"] = false;
        if(auth()->user()){
            /** city */
            $fav_cities = auth()->user()->favoriteCities->pluck("id");

            if(in_array($city["city_id"],$fav_cities->toArray())){
                $city["is_fav"] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    dd($data);
```

This code block shows it without "is_fave". But I want to add "is_fav" key. Therefore,
I added address pointer to my array inside the foreach as follow;

```
foreach ($data as &$city){
    ...
}
dd($data);
```

And now it works, so "is_fav" key has been added.

Could you explain why it's necessary?

Comment: Because the `&` makes it a referenced variable. without it you change the $city variable inside the foreach only, the $data variable does not change.

Comment: You can also use `for` loop with indexes if you want to change $data and if you want to avoid `&`.

Comment: "In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference." Docs for reference https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in this scenario the foreach splits it and creates a new variable. So that $city doesn't affect the value of the array. You can use this alternative way;

```
foreach ($data as $key=>$city){
  $data[$key]["is_fav"] = false;
  if(auth()->user()){
      /** city */
      $fav_cities = auth()->user()->favoriteCities->pluck("id");

      if(in_array( $data[$key]["city_id"],$fav_cities->toArray())){
         $data[$key]["is_fav"] = true;
      }
  }
}
```